# Referencing values in a different column with matching name in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

Getting stumped. How would I create a new column `items_delta`. I want `items_delta` to be a value that uses the column name, items, and last date. I need to find the delta between two different dates for the same name.

Ex: For name = A, the latest date is 12/14, and the items = 150. For name = A, I want the difference in items now compared to the items from the most previous date only. So essentially for name = A, I want (150 - 120)/120 = 0.25 which is the difference from the two latest dates.

```
Test Table

id     name     items     last_date
1      A        150       12/14/15
2      B        100       12/14/15
3      C        50        12/14/15
4      A        120       12/13/15
5      B        110       12/13/15
6      B        90        12/12/15
7      A        110       12/12/15
8      A        100       12/11/15
9      A        150       12/10/15
10     C        35        12/10/15
```

What I want:

```
Test Table 2

id     name     items     last_date    items_delta
1      A        150       12/14/15     0.25
2      B        100       12/14/15     -0.09
3      C        50        12/14/15     0.43
```

Relatively new to mySQL, please be gentle.

Comment: @JakeGould much appreciated :). very new to all of this. no excuse though. I'll be aware next time.

Comment: This would probably be easier on the application side. Also, having dates as strings is going to make things a lot more complicated to find the "previous day."